# Can I use a PWM HHO Controller to control a brushless DC motor?

Tags: arduino, brushless-motor

I'm an electronics newbie.

The part I'm talking about is [this](http://www.ebay.in/itm/221636836855?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649):

```
DC 10-50v 12V 24V 48V 3000W 60A amps DC Motor Speed Control PWM HHO Controller
```

My question is, can this type of part be used to control brushless DC motors?

Comment: What does "HHO" stand for?

Answer (score 2):

Practically all brushless motors require 3 independent power connections, each one at the appropriate frequency and 3 different phases. Those 3 power cables are typically connected to a [brushless ESC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/electronic_speed_control).

Practically all DC motor speed controllers (including DC electronic speed controllers for brushed DC motors), including the one you link to, only have 2 output power connections.

The 2 outputs of a DC motor speed controller are not enough to drive the 3 inputs of a brushless motor

[image: image of brushless motor, showing the 3 thick cables coming out of the motor]

(photo from ["RC Hobby Mysteries: What is Brushless Motor?"](http://blog.mbuynow.com/rc-hobby-mysteries-what-is-brushless-motor/))

[image]

(diagram from ["Esky Helicopters FAQ: Brushed vs Brushless Motors"](https://www.eskyhelicopters.com/faq/brushless-motors.php))

DC motor speed controllers -- with 2 output power connections -- work with brushed DC motors that have 2 power connections.

Brushless ESCs -- with 3 output power connections -- work with brushless motors that have 3 power connections.

As far as I can tell, any other connection between any two of a DC motor speed controller, a brushless ESC, a brushed DC motor, and a brushless motor, won't do anything useful.